# Let $d \in \mathbb{Z}$, $d > 1$. Determine all the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ which are prime or maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $d \in \mathbb{Z}$, $d > 1$. Determine all the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ which are prime or maximal

I know that $m\mathbb{Z}/md\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ **as rings without identity** if
and only if $(d,m)=1$.

I've been stuck on this problem for a good while. Is anyone is able to help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Find an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42076/on-proving-every-ideal-of-mathbbz-n-is-principal)

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650060

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

1. An ideal of a quotient ring $R/I$ has the form $J/I$ where $J$ is an ideal of $R$ containing $I$.
2. The ideals of $\Bbb Z$ are of the form $n\Bbb Z$ for some $n≥0$.
3. The third isomorphism theorem states that $(R/I) \; / \; (J/I) \cong R/J$
4. In a PID (such as $\Bbb Z$), an ideal $I$ is prime iff it is maximal.

Answer:

> The prime ideals are exactly of the form $p\Bbb Z / d\Bbb Z$, where $p$ is a prime number that divides $d$. The maximal ideals are also exactly of this form.